# Recommendations to understand stochastic version of Benders?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, stochastic-programming, benders-decomposition

I successfully understood and implemented a Benders algorithm for the deterministic version of the problem I am studying.

However, I have some issues now diving into the stochastic model. I have the mathematical foundations ready for two-stage stochastic programming but I don't know how to combine it with Benders now.

Do you know good resources where I can learn about this? Maybe even an example implementation in C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in C++, but SDDP.jl implements Benders for two-stage stochastic programming (as well as SDDP for multi-stage).

There are a few tutorials which work though the algorithm:

- https://sddp.dev/stable/tutorial/example_newsvendor/
- https://sddp.dev/stable/explanation/theory_intro/

But both these tutorials are pedagogical. They do not include the tricks that a high quality implementation needs. (I'm obviously biased, but instead of implementing your own algorithm, you could just use SDDP.jl.)